# Is DirectX 11 compute capable of writing more than 10k vertices to a RWStructuredBuffer?

Tags: directx, directx-11, compute-shader

I have a vertex buffer with an unordered access view, which I'm using to fill the vertices using a compute shader, which treats the UAV as a RWStructuredBuffer, using an equivalent struct to the vertex definition. There are 216000 vertices (i.e. 60 x 60 x 60). But my compute shader seems to fill only about 8000 of them, leaving the rest with their initial values. Is there a limit on the number of elements in a structured buffer that can be written in this way?

Comment: There is not a limitation like that, but it is easy to mess with final index computation using the system semantics. Without a bit of code showing it and your thread group configuration, impossible to provide a better answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, it's a yes-or-no question. But having found the answer elsewhere I'll elaborate below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, if you turn on DirectX error-checking, assigning the UAV of a vertex buffer as a RWStructuredBuffer in the shader is considered to be an error. So although this actually works (for a limited number of vertices), it's not supported.